# variable is not going to next php page by header()

Tags: php

I am trying to send classes_id variable from p1.php to p2.php by this at
code in p1.php

```
$url = "exam_excel/dynamic-result.php?c_id=$classes_id";
header("Location: ".$url);
```

code in php2

```
$classes_id = $_GET['$c_id'];
$SQL="SELECT `admissionnumber`,`pre_name`,`pre_fathersoccupation`,`pre_motheroccupation` FROM `es_preadmission` WHERE `pre_class`='$c_id'";
```

Getting blank result.

Need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

page 2 should be

`classes_id = $_GET['c_id'];`

no $

Answer (score -1):

you have to send like this because you're concatenating the variable

```
$url = "exam_excel/dynamic-result.php?c_id=".$classes_id;
header("Location: ".$url);
```

page 2 should be

```
classes_id = $_GET['c_id'];
```

Comment: It will work without concatenating the variable. PHP can accept variable within double quotes.